# fnmatch does not display all filenames that match

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, filenames

I have a folder containing 5 files named respectively '**out1.jpg**', '**out2a.jpg**', '**out2b.jpg**', '**out3.jpg**' and '**out4.jpg**' in addition to other files in different formats.
I have this Python script which is supposed to print all the filenames that match:

```
import fnmatch
import os

c = 1
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'out'+str(c)+'*.jpg'):
        print(file)
        c +=1
```

However, when I run this script,the output is limited to the following:

```
out1.jpg
out2a.jpg
out3.jpg
```

Anyone please has an idea how to change the script in order to display all the filenames that match (which are the 5 filenames that I mentioned)?

Comment: Could you clarify which of the files you want to match on? Is it all 5, or only a subset of those that you listed?

Comment: As I know, according to the condition `if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'out'+str(c)+'*.jpg')`, it should display the 5 filenames that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are increasing `c` on each iteration (well, on each iteration that found a match but anyway...), so it cannot obviously match "out2a.jpg" AND "out2b.jpg". Assuming you want all file names that match "out" + some number + eventually something else, you can use character ranges instead; ie:

```
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'out[0-9]*.jpg'):
        print(file)
```

NB : you might have to adjust the exact fnmatch pattern according to your needs and what you have in your directory.

You can also use `glob.glob` instead, which is both simpler and (according to the doc) more efficient:

```
import glob
for file in glob("out[0-9]*.jpg"):
    print(file)
```

EDIT :

> I totally understand why it does not display out2a.jpg and out2b.jpg together, but I didn't get why out4.jpg is not displayed!

Quite simply because `os.listdir()` does not necessarily returns the filenames in the same order as you seemed to expect (on my linux station here, "out4.jpg" comes before the other "outXXX.jpg" files). You can inspect what's happening just by adding a couple prints:

```
c = 1
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    exp = 'out{}*.jpg'.format(c)
    print("file: {} - c : {} - exp : {}".format(file, c, exp))
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, exp):
        print(file)
        c +=1
```

And the result here:

```
file: sofnm.py~ - c : 1 - exp : out1*.jpg
file: out4.jpg - c : 1 - exp : out1*.jpg
file: out2b.jpg - c : 1 - exp : out1*.jpg
file: out1.jpg - c : 1 - exp : out1*.jpg
out1.jpg
file: out2a.jpg - c : 2 - exp : out2*.jpg
out2a.jpg
file: sofnm.py - c : 3 - exp : out3*.jpg
file: out42a.jpg - c : 3 - exp : out3*.jpg
file: out3.jpg - c : 3 - exp : out3*.jpg
out3.jpg
```

As you can see, your assumption that `os.listdir()` would return the files in a given order (starting with "out1.jpg" and ending with "out4.jpg") was wrong. As a general rule, when your code don't behave as you expect, tracing the code execution (and the relevant values) is most often the simplest way to find out why.

Comment: I totally understand why it does not display out2a.jpg and out2b.jpg together, but I didn't get why out4.jpg is not displayed!

Comment: @singrium have you printed the result of `os.listdir()` ? On my station here (linux box), "out4.jpg" comes before any other "outXXX.jpg" file.

Comment: I am talking about the script I wrote, not yours.
The script that you shared works well.

Comment: @singrium yes, that's how I understood it. Cf my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Everything seems logical to me now.

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing c after a file match, it is quite possible that file name is out2a.jpg but the value of c is 1. So, it will not match. You should either list all the files in ascending order so that out1 will come before out2 in listdir or you should use a generic numeric match instead of one by one like shown below:

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    #print(file)
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'out[0-9]*.jpg'):
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Running through this for loop, you're checking each file in the directory against a very specific file name (first `out1*.jpg`, then `out2*.jpg`) with no guarantee that the order of these files matches. When I tried to run the code locally for example, it first compared out2a.jpg with the pattern `out1*.jpg`, then out2b.jpg with `out2*.jpg`, then `test.py` (the script) with `out3*.jpg`.

You'd be better off using a module like `glob` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to search for 'out*.jpg': `glob.glob('out[0-9]*.jpg')`.